# How to detect what the site template is in SPFx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

In SPFx modern sites, how can I detect what site template it is? In a shared tenant environment, I want to be able to be able to deploy them tenant wide, but disable them on certain sites (that are used by other organization). I was thinking of detecting them based on what site template is used. Anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: hi @Omega. Do I understand correctly, that one organization in the tenant uses exclusively Modern Team site templates and the other one only Communication sites? This is a really unusual scenario. if that's not the case, what kind of site templates do you mean?

Comment: Everyone could be using a modern (commuication or team) or a classic site, we can't control what they use. My team will try to use only modern. The idea is that if we make something that's tenant wide, and someone from another organization adds it to their page, we can detect it and block it. I was thinking of checking what site template the current site is. Maybe if I can detect it, I can see if its from my organization and block it that way. Then we just ensure all sites in our organization uses that template.

Comment: I see. if you don't have a site url naming convention for different organization, you can use custom Property Bag Key-value pair. For example, all your sites, you can add a new property called "Organization" and populate it with the name of your team/organization. Then, in your JavaScript/Typescript, you can read it and decide whether you want to run your code or terminate it.

Comment: For property bag I know in on prem versions you can use SP designer to set it. How can we do it using modern tools? Can it be set in the pnp provisioning process? We don't want to set it manually for each site created.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, you can add property bags to your PnPProvisioning template: ` <pnp:PropertyBagEntries>
        <pnp:PropertyBagEntry Key="ORGANIZATION" Value="MY_ORGANIZATION_A" Overwrite="true" />
        <pnp:PropertyBagEntry Key="docid_enabled" Value="1" Overwrite="true" />
      </pnp:PropertyBagEntries>`